# Cannot GET /api/v1/ , MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to test if my serving is working on post man.  I tried pasting this `http://localhost:80/api/v1/`

and i got, `Cannot GET /api/v1/`

On my terminal on vs code, it looks like the server is running because it shows
`LISTENING TO PORT: 80 db  connected`.

here is my code

**env file:**

```
PORT=80
MONGO_URL =myurl
```

**routes/transaction.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**index.js:**

```
const express = require('express')
const cors= require('cors')
const { db } = require('./db/db')
const {readdirSync} = require('fs')
const app = express()

require('dotenv').config()

const PORT =  process.env.PORT

//midwares
//data is in json
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())


//routes
readdirSync('./routes').map((route)=> app.use('/api/v1',require('./routes/' + route)))

const server = ()=>{
    db()
    app.listen(PORT,()=>{
        console.log('LISTENING TO PORT:',PORT);
    })
}

server()
```

I am using atlas, but I have also tried using mongoDB compass and i still get the same error

Comment: Quick test... try it without the trailing `/`, ie `http://localhost:80/api/v1`